# gae-sessions 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'current_session'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, gae-sessions

I'm trying to get gae-sessions working, but am having an issue.

I've logged inside of appengine_config.py and inside of webapp_add_wsgi_middleware and it is being called.

I've logged inside the libs `__init__.py` and it's running `__init__`, `__call__` and `my_start_response` inside SessionMiddleware without issue.

My problem is that the second I try to actually use the session with:

```
session = get_current_session()
```

I get this:

```
    session = get_current_session()
  File "gaesessions\__init__.py", line 38, in get_current_session
    return _tls.current_session
AttributeError: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'current_session'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem seems to be that I can only call get_current_session within a get request handler. If I try to call a function in another module from the get request handler, that itself requests the session, I get the above error.

Comment: So what is your sollution?

Comment: You need to add the gae-sessions installation code in your WSGI middleware  https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions#installation

Comment: You should add this as an answer, my answer was just to not do the thing that caused the error. :P